# How to dynamically adjust positioning of a VerticalStackLayout inside a Grid?

Tags: xaml, maui

I'm creating an app using MAUI and I'm trying to make it so an `ImageButton` and `SearchBar` nested in a `VerticalStackLayout` move positioning based on the dynamically created `CollectionView`.

[image]

[image]

This is the code for the UI:

```
    <Grid>
    <FlexLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView x:Name="taskList">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Task">
                        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="15">
                            <Entry Text="{Binding name}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                            <Entry Text="{Binding departmentsString}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                <Entry Text="{Binding status}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <Entry Text="{Binding deadline}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                                <Entry Text="{Binding author.fullName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding description}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="15">
            <Entry Placeholder="Name" x:Name="nameTxt"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Department" x:Name="departTxt"/>
            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                <inputs:SfComboBox x:Name="statusTxt" Placeholder="Status" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="Green" DropDownIconColor="Green"/>
                <Entry Placeholder="deadline" x:Name="deadlineTxt"/>
                <Entry Placeholder="Author" x:Name="authorTxt"/>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Entry Placeholder="Description" x:Name="descTxt"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </FlexLayout>
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" >
        <SearchBar Placeholder="Search" x:Name="searchBar" TextChanged="searchBar_TextChanged" MaxLength="30" MaximumWidthRequest="200"/>
        <ImageButton Aspect="AspectFill" x:Name="addBtn" Source="plus.png" BackgroundColor="Black" Clicked="addBtn_Clicked" HeightRequest="64" WidthRequest="64"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Grid>
```

I have tried every different type of Layout but nothing works.
What should I do?

Comment: That's not how grid layout works. You can align things vertically or horizontally inside a grid cell or in worst case you can give margins to an item to move it inside a grid cell.

Comment: @tataelm then what do you recommend doing?

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?